# Must I reapply for an ESTA following a change in employment status?

Tags: esta

I had my ESTA approved last year when I didn't have a job hence put `NO` under `DO YOU HAVE A CURRENT OR PREVIOUS EMPLOYER?`. Since then I have both received and ended employment so if I were to apply for an ESTA now I should answer `YES` to `DO YOU HAVE A CURRENT OR PREVIOUS EMPLOYER?`

I plan to go to America and stay with some friends for around 2 months before returning home and looking for another job.

When I tried to update the ESTA information I discovered that you may only make changes to information related to your Travel Information.

Will I need to apply for a new ESTA that contains the correct information or will I be able to get by with this one and will the fact that I recently left my job or that I plan to be there for 2 months be an issue?

Comment: @pnuts `DO YOU HAVE A CURRENT OR PREVIOUS EMPLOYER?` Note the 'previous employer' part. The job I left yesterday is now my previous employer. Not sure why the downvote

Comment: @pnuts +1 that's an answer!

Comment: @pnuts all travelers are asked for a US address, so "might" should be "will."

Comment: @pnuts no time this weekend. Why don't you post one? Except for that one minor detail, your comment was a fine response to the question; I don't understand why you deleted it.

Comment: @pnuts I don't doubt that if he failed to present a properly completed customs form that they would add the charge to his indictment. But anyway they ask all commercial travelers, in writing, before they arrive at the border, by requiring the commercial carriers to distribute the customs forms *en route.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a little follow up:

I got through with no problems. In theory I guess I should have maybe updated my ESTA to reflect this minor change but they didn't mention anything.

So it looks like the answer to this question is 'No' you don't need to update your ESTA but probably should to be safe.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to follow up and share your experience.